# Yii2: Frontend user logout but backend remains logged in

Tags: php, yii2, user-controls, logout

I’m having a problem, when I logout from either frontend or backend, the other one remains log in. I have been searching online for the solutions but did not find anything like this. What should I change so that when I logout from frontend or backend, the other one must logout.

Log in is working fine for both:

```
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::$app->user->logout();

    return $this->goHome();
}
```

Comment: You will need to give us more info for proper answer. For example: Does your backend/frontend run on same domain? What is your configuration of user component in frontend/backend? `Yii::$app->user->logout()`  removes a session and identity cookie. If your backend is run on different domain or uses different identity cookie than frontend the `Yii::$app->user->logout()` called in frontend won't be able to remove it for backend.

Comment: Yes, i'm using different domain, is there any method that i can call the logout function for backend? But login is working fine, when frontend login, backend will also login.

Comment: The login is probably working fine because of cookies. Let's say your frontend runs on www.example.org and your backend on admin.example.org. Once you've logged into frontend the cookies set is valid for entire `example.org` domain. So if you go to backend you are automatically logged in thanks to that cookie. But sessions are not shared like that. When you logout on frontend the session on backend keeps existing. If you want to logout on both I would suggest that you redirect user to backend logout after logout on frontend than redirect him back to frontend.

Comment: Another option might be to store logout information in DB and force logout the user once they try to access backend after logout.

Comment: i tried redirecting using below code in  frontend controller.

public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl(['site/logout']));
    }

But receiver error #405, "Method Not Allowed. This URL can only handle the following request methods: POST." Is there a way i can add "data-method" => 'POST' into it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the controller's `redirect()` method uses HTTP headers to do the redirect and browser will always use GET method in that case. If you want to do the redirect like that you have to allow GET request for logout. The other option is to do the redirect using JS. But, if you are going that way, you don't even need to redirect user, simple ajax request to backend logout url should be enough to log user out of backend.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your frontend and backend main.php as below

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-auth', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        'name' => 'AuthSession',
    ],
```

once the identityCookie and sessions are identical, then you can manage your session from both frontend and backend.

Comment: tried this, but it's not working, same problem